# Fibonacci Decimal Number in Brazilian Math Olympiad

Tags: contest-math, divisibility, fibonacci-numbers

I came in contact with a problem that asks if the number $(10^{60} -1)r$ is integer, given that the number $r = 0,235831$, being this number formed according to the following rule:

> every digit after the first decimal place is equal to the residue in the division by 10 of the sum of the two previous digits.

The other answers are the ones that claim that $(10^{25} -1)r$ is integer and that $(10^{17} -1)r$ is integer, which are wrong according to the olympiad organization.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hint: Check the periodicity in the decimal expansion of $r$.

Comment: Check http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/fibonacci/fib.htm, particularly Result A #7

Comment: Hint. (10^n - 1)r is an integer, if and only if the decimal digits of r has period n.